# How can I keep Firefox from clearing Flash Files downloaded from sites like ArmorGames.com?

Tags: firefox, flash, firefox-extensions

How can I keep Firefox from clearing very large Flash Files downloaded from sites like ArmorGames.com? Is there an option or addon for that?

I don't want to redownload and redownload the same Flash Files everytime I visit the game page.

Answer (score 0):

About Firefox, which is the version ?
I tried with Firefox 6.0

Options -> Privacy -> Retention Policy = private use parameters for history
on the "Allow cookies" line -> Exception.

Add "ArmorGames.com" with "authorized"

When your browser will be closed, if all cookies are deleted, only them with the "authorized" permission will be keep.

Remember : If you use a software like CCleaner 
CCleaner -> Options -> Cookies -> Cookies to keep; add "ArmorGames.com"

Hope it help you

Comment: No, I'm good with my cookies and session settings. What I want is that if I clear my cache, it will skip deleting *.swf files, like they are protected.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct way, but increasing your cache should make it more likely that the downloaded files are retained - it is in options ->  options -> offline storage in firefox

[image]

Comment: This is one step closer to what I need, but I need something, like an addon where, if I clear my cache, it will skip deleting *.swf files, like they are protected.